# Linker fail: member in archive is not an object

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, g++, mingw

I'm trying to build Open CASCADE (6.7.1) library with 64bit mingw on Windows 7 (I am using *x86_64-4.9.1-release-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1* from [mingw-w64 project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/4.9.1/threads-posix/seh/)).

When it comes to linking, it fails with an error and I have no idea what could be wrong. The linker command generated by cmake is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe     -shared -o ..\out\bin\libTKernel.dll -Wl,--out-implib,..\out\lib\libTKernel.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -LC:\msys64\home\user\tcl8.5.16\build  -LC:\msys64\home\user\freetype-2.5.3 -ladvapi32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

And the produced error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ..\out\bin\libTKernel.dll
CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a: member CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a(FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj) in archive is not an object
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
TKernel\CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir\build.make:11422: recipe for target 'out/bin/libTKernel.dll' failed
```

This is how the files are compiled:

```
Building CXX object TKernel/CMakeFiles/TKernel.dir/__/__/src/FSD/FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj
cd /d TKernel && C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe   -DCSFDB -DTKernel_EXPORTS -DWNT -D_OCC64 -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -MP -Wall -O3 -DNDEBUG -DNo_Exception @CMakeFiles/TKernel.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -MM -D__FSD_DLL -D__MMgt_DLL -D__OSD_DLL -D__Plugin_DLL -D__Quantity_DLL -D__Resource_DLL -D__SortTools_DLL -D__Standard_DLL -D__StdFail_DLL -D__Storage_DLL -D__TColStd_DLL -D__TCollection_DLL -D__TShort_DLL -D__Units_DLL -D__UnitsAPI_DLL -D__IncludeLibrary_DLL -D__Dico_DLL -D__NCollection_DLL -D__Message_DLL -o CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir\__\__\src\FSD\FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj -c ..\..\src\FSD\FSD_BinaryFile.cxx
```

If I check the `objects.a` file with `nm`, the contents are `.obj`, but "File format not recognized" doesn't look good... but don't know what exactly does that mean...

```
$ nm objects.a
C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\nm.exe: FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj: File format not recognized
C:\msys64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\nm.exe: FSD_CmpFile.cxx.obj: File format not recognized
...
```

Output from `file` command:

```
$ file objects.a
objects.a: current ar archive

$  file __/__/src/FSD/FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj
__/__/src/FSD/FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I also tried to remove the `--whole-archive` option from the linker command, but that leads to another error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ..\out\bin\libTKernel.dll
CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I run ranlib on the file, it doesn't help.

Any ideas are appreciated.

**edit:** Ok, so I guess that the problem is caused by -MM flag, that was used for the build. So it didn't really compile the files, if I understand it correctly.

However I found  [OCE](https://github.com/tpaviot/oce) project, which is some sort of community edition of OCC and it is quite mingw-ready, so I'm gonna use that version and see how it goes...

Comment: It seems like the `.obj` files are not in any object format your MinGW toolchain recognizes... you checked with `nm`, what does the more generic `file` have to say about `objects.a` and its contents?

Comment: At this time it should be obvious that the error message is obviously correct: If `FSD_BinaryFile.cxx.obj` is "ASCII test", it can't be linkable. Seeing how it is generated by CMake ("`ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\TKernel.dir/objects.a <...>") and CMake is not known to break "just like that", I would look askance at the CMake configuration. I don't know the first thing about this OpenCASCADE you're trying to compile, but it seems they managed to come up with a config that breaks on (your) MinGW...

Comment: @DevSolar: thanks, I'm not very familiar with CMake, so I guess I'd better get started...