# Qt + Cmake-GUI + OpenCV - Linking CXX shared library error

Tags: qt, opencv, cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying to setup the OpenCV image processing library v3.4.1 with QT v5.10.1 and cmake-gui using the guide here: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows. I am using Windows 7 64bit.

I have followed all instructions exactly but when I run the command `mingw32-make` I get the following error:

```
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libopencv_core341.dll
CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.a: member CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir/objects.
a(vs_version.rc.obj) in archive is not an object
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:2329: recipe for target 'bin/
libopencv_core341.dll' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [bin/libopencv_core341.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1624: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_cor
e.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have searched endlessly for a solution but nothing has worked thus far.

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Which generator did you set when you run cmake "configure" ?

Comment: @MizuxDev According to the guide: "Then click Configure, let cmake create the build directory, and choose the following settings: 
 Specify the generator for this project: MinGW Makefiles
 Specify native compilers, next
 Compilers C: D:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\gcc.exe
 Compilers C++: D:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\g++.exe
 Finish"

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/168538/building-opencv-with-mingw-gcc-710-and-cmake-390-windresexe-unknown-option-w/ Does it help ?
ie verify if `ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS` is uncheck

Comment: @MizuxDev I have already unchecked that option. I get the same error with it enabled or disabled.

Comment: Silly question, why don't using `mingw64` like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136097/linker-fail-member-in-archive-is-not-an-object (kind of same problem than your but no answer unfortunately)

Comment: @MizuxDev Well I was simply following the guide which said to use 32 bit. Also, I installed 32 bit version of QT as instructed: "select components: Qt-Qt5.9-MingGW 5.3.0 32 bit
 select components: Qt-Tools-MinGW 5.3.0".

Answer (score 0):

I hope this you've found a solution to this problem. I suggest you first install Git. Then add the path on the system environment variables. Then open cmak-gui and delete the cache. Then on the folder, you were trying to create cmake file. delete them also.
Then configure and create through cmake-gui again. 
It works for me.
Good luck